# uib-tabset shows content while its disabled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a tabset and if the first tab is disabled the content is still showing on page load. When another tab is clicked, the first tab is disabled and can not be clicked which is good.
(The disable attribute is set by authorization/angular)

here is a simplified  example:

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Title</h2>

        <div data-uib-tabset="">
            <div data-uib-tab="" index="0" data-heading="tab 1" disable="true')">
                <div class="col-md-12 vertical-gutter">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-uib-tab="" index="1" data-heading="tab 2">
                <div class="col-md-12 vertical-gutter">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-uib-tab="" index="2" data-heading="tab 3">
                <div class="col-md-12 vertical-gutter">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do you hide the content for the disabled tab and make the "first active tab" active on page load?

An option is to use ng-show/ng-if but then I still need to make the "first active tab" active

Comment: With "first active tab" I mean the first enabled tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declared a variable in the controller. (vm.activeTab)
The value will be set by a function and in the frontend the value will be retrieved with angular.

Setting the active property will show the correct tab at the init pageload.

html:

```
<div data-uib-tabset="" active="vm.activeTab">
```

controller:

```
vm.activeTab = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

```
<div data-uib-tab="" index="0" data-heading="tab 1" disable="expression">
    <div class="col-md-12 vertical-gutter">
         <div ng-hide="expression">
             content
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Or just make another tab active by default if the n'th one is disabled

Comment: This will not work because it will only hide the content. you get a blank tab. I need to set the index of the first active tab. I can write a custom method for this.

I just need to know if there is a setting for doing this automatically.

Comment: the functionality you're describing isn't built-in but it's easy to implement. for example you can store an array of booleans in your controller, traverse them using something like `Array.prototype.find` and get your first enabled tab. i can patch up a live example if you want.